# Regex in script from variable using egrep

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to parse the variable A_DESTINATION (a directory) and only call out the words in between the /.../

```
case "$TR_TORRENT_INFO" in
    *test1.com*)
    A_DESTINATION=${A_DESTINATION}/Books/
    ;;
    *test2.com*)
    A_DESTINATION=${A_DESTINATION}/Movies/
    ;;
    *test3.com*)
    A_DESTINATION=${A_DESTINATION}/Music/
    ;;
    *)
    A_DESTINATION=${A_DESTINATION}/Miscellaneous/
    ;;
esac

test="$(egrep '\/([^/.]+)\/$' $A_DESTINATION)"
echo test
```

I've gotten a regex in my script but it's not returning the folder successfully (i.e. in this case, /Miscellaneous/) in my log. It's just displaying this:

```
+ A_DESTINATION=/mnt/sda1/Miscellaneous/
+ egrep \/([^/.]+)\/$ /mnt/sda1/Miscellaneous/
+ test=
+ echo test
test
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `grep` works against files, not arguments. You're passing the var as an argument, and so `grep` is treating the argument it as a file to search. Also, why not use `basename`?

Comment: I can't use basename because I need the directory (i.e. /Movies/) before the file, not the file. Thanks for the info... how can I use grep or an equivalent on an argument?

Comment: You can `echo "$A_DESTINATION" | egrep ...` or (if your shell supports here-strings) `egrep ... <<< "$A_DESTINATION"`. OTOH if you omit the trailing `/` in your assignments you could likely use the shell's built in parameter manipulation e.g. `"/${A_DESTINATION##*/}/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a final directory suffix to `$A_DESTINATION` and then extracting it again with `grep` or whatever, why not just use a separate variable (e.g. `$final`) in the `case` statement and add that to `$A_DESTINATION` afterwards?  For example:

```bash
case "$TR_TORRENT_INFO" in
    *test1.com*) final='Books' ;;
    *test2.com*) final='Movies' ;;
    *test3.com*) final='Music' ;;
              *) final='Miscellaneous' ;;
esac

A_DESTINATION="$A_DESTINATION/$final/"

echo "$final"
```

This works, is simpler and, IMO, is also easier to read.

BTW, the single-quotes around Books, Movies, etc aren't strictly necessary (because there are no spaces or shell metacharacters in the strings), but they don't hurt and IMO single-quoting fixed strings is a good-habit to get into.  It's also a reminder to use single-quotes if you want to add another case with a space in the final directory name (e.g. maybe something like `final='Other Junk' ;;`)

Answer (score 0):

Following [steeldrive's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424898/regex-in-script-from-variable-using-egrep#comment765871_424898) of leaving off the trailing `/` in the assignments:

```
case "$TR_TORRENT_INFO" in
    *test1.com*) A_DESTINATION="$A_DESTINATION/Books"  ;;
    *test2.com*) A_DESTINATION="$A_DESTINATION/Movies" ;;
    *test3.com*) A_DESTINATION="$A_DESTINATION/Music"  ;;
    *) A_DESTINATION="$A_DESTINATION/Miscellaneous"
esac
```

... or use a variable to hold the added path element [as cas suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424925/116858), which will be easier to read.

This will allow you to use either the `basename` utility or the `${parameter##word}` parameter substitution to get at the final part of the path in `$A_DESTINATION`.

The basename of a pathname does not need to be a file.  It's simply the last part of a path:

```
printf 'basename is "%s"\n' "${A_DESTINATION##*/}"
```

or

```
printf 'basename is "%s"\n' "$( basename "$A_DESTINATION" )"
```

When you later add a filename to the path, *then* include the `/` path separator:

```
filepath="$A_DESTINATION/$filename"
```

---

Your `egrep` command:

```
egrep '\/([^/.]+)\/$' $A_DESTINATION
```

This will instruct `egrep` to read `$A_DESTINATION` as a file and apply the given regular expression to it.

The following would have worked (assuming no trailing `/`), but you should use the above mentioned solution instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "$A_DESTINATION" | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

---

Don't use `test` as the name of a variable as it is also the name of a standard command.  There is no risk of "overloading" the command `test`, but it would potentially make the code confusing to read.